# The emulator process has terminated at 15/10/2023

Tags: flutter, android-studio, process, emulation

everyone!

**when i run the emulator it show this error msg in idea.log**

INFO - #com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager - C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_7_Pro_API_31
INFO - #com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager - C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_7_Pro_API_31
WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_7_Pro_API_31 is online, assuming it's not
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_7_Pro_API_31 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Found systemPath C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 3403.632812 MB at C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - OS: Windows 10
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.0.1
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 31 - Process finished with exit code 1
INFO - #com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager - C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_7_Pro_API_31
INFO - #com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager - C:\Users\user.android\avd\Pixel_7_Pro_API_31.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_7_Pro_API_31
WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_7_Pro_API_31 is online, assuming it's not

**But emulator is working Yesterday

i try to reinstall HAXM,update Android Studio,but still not working **